# Diskspd and high latency

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, storage

Hope someone can help here. 
I am trying to understand the high latency reported by Diskspd. Please help how to investigate this further.

OS : Windows server 2008

Local disk, Not SAN or NAS

RAID :10

Disk 15k RPM SAS

Command Line: diskspd.exe -b8K -d120 -o4 -h -L -t8 -W25 -r test.dat

Input parameters:

```
timespan:   1
-------------
duration: 120s
warm up time: 25s
cool down time: 0s
measuring latency
random seed: 0
path: 'test.dat'
    think time: 0ms
    burst size: 0
    software cache disabled
    hardware write cache disabled, writethrough on
    performing read test
    block size: 8192
    using random I/O (alignment: 8192)
    number of outstanding I/O operations: 4
    thread stride size: 0
    threads per file: 8
    using I/O Completion Ports
    IO priority: normal
```

> actual test time: 120.01s thread count:       8 proc count:       32

```
CPU |  Usage |  User  |  Kernel |  Idle
-------------------------------------------
   0|   2.24%|   0.53%|    1.70%|  97.77%
   1|   4.80%|   0.26%|    4.54%|  95.19%
   2|   2.12%|   0.30%|    1.82%|  97.89%
   3|   2.01%|   0.12%|    1.90%|  97.98%
   4|   2.09%|   0.84%|    1.25%|  97.92%
   5|   1.96%|   0.51%|    1.46%|  98.05%
   6|   1.99%|   0.74%|    1.25%|  98.02%
   7|   1.73%|   0.62%|    1.10%|  98.28%
   8|   0.04%|   0.04%|    0.00%|  99.98%
   9|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  10|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  11|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  12|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  13|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  14|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  15|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  16|   0.04%|   0.04%|    0.00%|  99.95%
  17|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  18|   0.09%|   0.08%|    0.01%|  99.91%
  19|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  20|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  21|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  22|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  23|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  24|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  25|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  26|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  27|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  28|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  29|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  30|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
  31|   0.00%|   0.00%|    0.00%| 100.02%
-------------------------------------------
avg.|   0.60%|   0.13%|    0.47%|  99.42%




Total IO
thread |  bytes    |I/Os  |MB/s |I/O per s | AvgLat| LatStdDev |  file
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 | 317480960 |38755 |2.52 |   322.94 |12.380 |13.745 | test.dat (20GB)
     2 | 316293120 |38610 |2.51 |   321.73 |12.428 |13.954 | test.dat (20GB)
     0 | 315326464 |38492 |2.51 |   320.75 |12.468 |13.751 | test.dat (20GB)
     3 | 321748992 |39276 |2.56 |   327.28 |12.218 |13.613 | test.dat (20GB)
     4 | 309526528 |37784 |2.46 |   314.85 |12.698 |14.042 | test.dat (20GB)
     5 | 304111616 |37123 |2.42 |   309.34 |12.926 |14.383 | test.dat (20GB)
     6 | 307445760 |37530 |2.44 |   312.73 |12.784 |14.207 | test.dat (20GB)
     7 | 307380224 |37522 |2.44 |   312.67 |12.787 |14.162 | test.dat (20GB)
----------------------------------  ----------------------------------------
total: 2499313664  |305092|19.86    2542.30|12.582 |13.982

Read IO
thread |bytes     | I/Os  | MB/s|I/O per s| AvgLat | LatStdDev|  file
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     0 |315326464 | 38492 |2.51 |  320.75 | 12.468 | 13.751 | test.dat (20GB)
     1 |317480960 | 38755 |2.52 |  322.94 | 12.380 | 13.745 | test.dat (20GB)
     2 |316293120 | 38610 |2.51 |  321.73 | 12.428 | 13.954 | test.dat (20GB)
     3 |321748992 | 39276 |2.56 |  327.28 | 12.218 | 13.613 | test.dat (20GB)
     4 |309526528 | 37784 |2.46 |  314.85 | 12.698 | 14.042 | test.dat (20GB)
     5 |304111616 | 37123 |2.42 |  309.34 | 12.926 | 14.383 | test.dat (20GB)
     6 |307445760 | 37530 |2.44 |  312.73 | 12.784 | 14.207 | test.dat (20GB)
     7 |307380224 | 37522 |2.44 |  312.67 | 12.787 | 14.162 | test.dat (20GB)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
total: 2499313664 | 305092|19.86|  2542.30| 12.582 | 13.982

Write IO
thread |bytes |I/Os| MB/s |I/O per s | AvgLat  | LatStdDev |  file
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     0 |0     |  0 | 0.00 | 0.00     |    0.000 |       N/A | test.dat (20GB)
     1 |0     |  0 | 0.00 | 0.00     |    0.000 |       N/A | test.dat (20GB)
     2 |0     |  0 | 0.00 | 0.00     |    0.000 |       N/A | test.dat (20GB)
     3 |0     |  0 | 0.00 | 0.00     |    0.000 |       N/A | test.dat (20GB)
     4 |0     |  0 | 0.00 | 0.00     |    0.000 |       N/A | test.dat (20GB)
     5 |0     |  0 | 0.00 | 0.00     |    0.000 |       N/A | test.dat (20GB)
     6 |0     |  0 | 0.00 | 0.00     |    0.000 |       N/A | test.dat (20GB)
     7 |0     |  0 | 0.00 | 0.00     |    0.000 |       N/A | test.dat (20GB)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
total:  0     |  0 | 0.00 | 0.00     |    0.000 |       N/A


  %-ile |  Read (ms) | Write (ms) | Total (ms)
----------------------------------------------
    min |      0.036 |        N/A |      0.036
   25th |      3.876 |        N/A |      3.876
   50th |      7.704 |        N/A |      7.704
   75th |     16.134 |        N/A |     16.134
   90th |     28.852 |        N/A |     28.852
   95th |     39.914 |        N/A |     39.914
   99th |     68.212 |        N/A |     68.212
3-nines |    112.176 |        N/A |    112.176
4-nines |    167.096 |        N/A |    167.096
5-nines |    208.167 |        N/A |    208.167
6-nines |    247.233 |        N/A |    247.233
7-nines |    247.233 |        N/A |    247.233
8-nines |    247.233 |        N/A |    247.233
9-nines |    247.233 |        N/A |    247.233
    max |    247.233 |        N/A |    247.233
```

Comment: 1) Do you have an antivirus installed? 2) How was the drive formatted? 3) Have you tried a block size of 64KB? 4) I see a latency of 13ms. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: This is a brand new server. This serve will be used to host sql server. I am looking the latency for the data drive to be between 7 and 10.

Comment: You didn't answer the first two questions. Please investigate that. If you don't have an AV installed, do you have any other sort of filter driver that is constantly monitoring I/O?